# How do I use GitHub Actions envrionment variables in a job called with workflow_call

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have 2 workflows: **CI/CD** and **Deploy**.

**Deploy** can be triggered manually (with `workflow_dispatch`) or by **CI/CD** (with `workflow_call`). It uses an `environment` named "dev" that contains 2 secrets: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

The **Deploy** workflow is successful when called manually. However, when it's called from **CI/CD**, it fails with

> Error: Credentials could not be loaded, please check your action inputs: Could not load credentials from any providers

Here are the relevant parts of my workflows:

#### **`.github/workflows/ci-cd.yaml`**

```yaml
name: CI/CD
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  ci:
    name: CI Checks
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # ... (run static analysis and tests)

  deploy-to-qa:
    name: Deploy to staging
    needs: [ ci ]
    uses: org/repo/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml@main
    with:
      AWS_REGION: us-east-1
```

#### **`.github/workflows/deploy.yaml`**

```yaml
name: Deploy
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      AWS_REGION: { required: true, type: string }
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      AWS_REGION:
        required: true
        default: us-east-1

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      ###############
      # THIS STEP FAILS when run with workflow_call (but succeeds with workflow_dispatch)
      ###############
      - name: Configure aws creds
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }}
```

The error:
[image: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1 error: Credential could not be loaded]

Comment: The workflow_call needs secrets to be sent separately. [Check this blog](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-03-github-actions-simplify-using-secrets-with-reusable-workflows/)

Comment: Thank you @GuiFalourd. Adding `secrets: inherit` to `jobs.deploy-to-qa` solved it, allowing both manual and called deployments.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I would recommend posting this solution as an answer, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should define that as input params in the `workflow_call` section and pass them in the caller workflow. Like:

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      AWS_REGION: { required: true, type: string }
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: { required: true, type: string }
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: { required: true, type: string }
```

and use it like:

```
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ inputs.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ inputs.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }}
```

In this way you could lost the ability to call with a `workflow_dispatch`. In order to support that also, you could try this approach:

```
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ inputs.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ||  secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ inputs.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ||  secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }}
```

Not tested, may require an intermediary step to resolve this part

Answer (score 2):

The [workflow_call](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_call) needs `secrets` to be sent separately:

> A map of the secrets that can be used in the called workflow.

Example

```
on:
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      access-token:
        description: 'A token passed from the caller workflow'
        required: false

jobs:

  pass-secret-to-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    # passing the secret to an action
      - name: Pass the received secret to an action
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.access-token }}

  # passing the secret to a nested reusable workflow
  pass-secret-to-workflow:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/my-workflow
    secrets:
       token: ${{ secrets.access-token }}
```

[Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callsecrets)

---

Moreover, according to [this blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-03-github-actions-simplify-using-secrets-with-reusable-workflows/), you can inherit secrets now:

> GitHub Actions simplifies using secrets with reusable workflows with the `secrets: inherit` keyword.

> Previously when passing secrets to a reusable workflow, you had to
> pass each secret as a separate argument. Now you can simply pass the
> `secrets: inherit` to the reusable workflow and the secrets will be
> inherited from the calling workflow.